# Interpolation type theorem for multiplication operator on measure space. Is it trivial?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, operator-theory, lp-spaces, interpolation-theory

In my notes I found the following result without proof or reference:

Let $(\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a Borel measure space, with $\mu$ positive and $\sigma$-finite. Let $g,h : \mathcal{M} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^+$ be two measurable functions.

If $\| g \psi \|_{L^2} \leqslant c \| h \psi \| _{L^2}$ holds for some dense set of test functions $\psi$, then for all $s \in [0,1]$ :

$$\| g^s \psi \|_{L^2} \leqslant c^s \| h^s \psi \| _{L^2}.$$

Does anyone know if this result is true ? Do you have a reference for the proof ?

Is it a consequence of the Riesz-Thorin / Stein-Weiss type interpolation theorems ? If so can you please explain how (see e.g. https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247a.1.06f/notes2.pdf)

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I found an article by Kato "A generalization of the Heinz inequality" 1961 that proves this in a more general setting.

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1195523678